# How to get JInternalFrame Titlebar properly styled by Insubstantial

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, substance

I have a problem with the style of JInternalFrames under Insubstantial 7.0. I'm working with Eclipse and WindowBuilder for Swing. In the Widowbuilder Preview, JInternalFrames, that are dropped to a DesktopPane, have a nice shiny titlebar(using GraphiteGlassSkin). But when i start the program, the titlebar and the client space of all JInternalFrames are just drawn in the same grey without any difference.

How can i get those titlebars to be shiny at runtime?

Best regards,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Runtime you can change [LookAndFeel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

1) thenafter you have to call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(`[Top-Level Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)`);`

2) if is there some `Backgroung Task` you have to wrap code into `invokeAndWait()`, if isn't/aren't there any `Backgroung Task` then with success by using `invokeLater()`

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new GraphiteGlassSkinLookAndFeel());
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot. unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. it seems, that the titlePane ist not instanciated at all.

Comment: some Themes change that e.g. SubstanceOfficeSilver2007LookAndFeel, if you download code source for Substance, then in the java Folder -> Check.java is the best guide for the Custom Java Look & Feel on this world :-)

Comment: downvote because this is a generic look and feel answer to a specific question about two specific tools and the look and feel.  This answer will fix nothing.